# how to convert NSString into Float64 in ios? and retrieving text from TextField

Tags: ios, floating-point, nsstring, textfield

Given NSString *test = @"2.98", how do I convert this value into float so I can actually use them.

Also, is what you retrieve from TextField always of type NSString*??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[@"2.98" floatValue];`

And yes, a text of an UITextField is always a pointer to an `NSString` object.

Comment: `Float64` is defined as `typedef double Float64;`, it's better to use `[@"2.98" doubleValue];` instead.